# How to get running total for multiple users in a single request?

Tags: mysql

Users purchase fixed duration periods, e.g. 10 days. As soon as order is paid the period starts. Overlapping periods sums. Table of orders simplified:

```
id  uid  ts
1   10    0 
2   10    9
3   20   10
4   30   15
5   10   25
6   10   26
7   10   27
```

In the example user #10 has a sequence of 2 10-day periods from 0 to 20 paid, then blank period, then three 10-day periods in a row prolong each other giving a total of 30 resulting in a paid span from 25 to 55.

User #20 has paid period from 10 to 20. User #30 from 15 to 25.

To retrieve end of last paid period for a particular user I use variable:

```
@paid_till := 10 + GREATEST(IF(@paid_till is null, 0, @paid_till), ts)
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b0d54/1)

**How to get `paid_till` days for all users mentioned with a single request?**

```
uid  paid_till
10   55 
20   20
30   25
```

For the user #10 here's a timeline:

```
User: #10

time: 0....10....20....30....40....50....60
orders:
      1----
          2----
#2 shifts after #1 ends:
           2----
                    5---
                     6---
                      7---
#6 shifts after #5 ends:
                        6---
#7 shifts after shifted #6 ends:
                            7----

Latest end of paid period for the user is time: 50
```

Comment: `In the example user #10 has a sequence of 2 10-day periods from 0 to 20 paid, then blank period, then three 10-day periods in a row prolong each other giving a total of 30 resulting in a paid span from 25 to 55.` Have to admit, I'm struggling to see any of that

Comment: @Strawberry added some ascii art to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the query if you add a new row and the ts is not bigger than the last ts.
It increases the paid_till with 10 else it takes the new ts + 10 days.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders (
>   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>   uid INT,
>   ts INT
> );
>
> INSERT INTO orders (uid, ts) VALUES (10, 0), (10, 9), (20, 10), (30,15), (10,25), (10,26), (10,27);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECt * From orders ORDER by uid,ts;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | uid | ts
> -: | --: | -:
>  1 |  10 |  0
>  2 |  10 |  9
>  5 |  10 | 25
>  6 |  10 | 26
>  7 |  10 | 27
>  3 |  20 | 10
>  4 |  30 | 15
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> IF(@uidold = uid,IF(@newts >= ts,@newts:= @newts+10,@newts := ts +10),@newts :=ts +10) paid_till,
> @uidold := a1.uid uid
> FROM 
> (SELECt * From orders ORDER by uid,ts) a1,(SELECT @uidold := 0) a ,(SELECT @newts := 0) b
> ```
>
> ```
> paid_till | uid
> --------: | --:
>        10 |  10
>        20 |  10
>        35 |  10
>        45 |  10
>        55 |  10
>        20 |  20
>        25 |  30
> ```

> ```
> SELECT uid,MAX(paid_till) paid_till
> FROM
> (SELECT
> IF(@uidold = uid,IF(@newts >= ts,@newts:= @newts+10,@newts := ts +10),@newts :=ts +10) paid_till,
> @uidold := a1.uid uid
> FROM 
> (SELECt * From orders ORDER by uid,ts) a1,(SELECT @uidold := 0) a ,(SELECT @newts := 0) b) c
> GROUP By uid
> ```
>
> ```
> uid | paid_till
> --: | --------:
>  10 |        55
>  20 |        20
>  30 |        25
> ```

> ```
> SELECT a.uid, MAX_till +(b.addcount * 10) paid_till
> FROM 
> (SELECT MAX(ts) MAX_till,uid FROM orders Group by uid) a inner join
> (SELECT Count(*) addcount,ts,uid FROM orders Group BY uid,ts)b ON a.uid = b.uid AND a.MAX_till = ts
> ORDER BY uid
> ```
>
> ```
> uid | paid_till
> --: | --------:
>  10 |        37
>  20 |        20
>  30 |        25
> ```

> ```
> SELECT Count(*),ts,uid FROM orders Group BY uid,ts
> ```
>
> ```
> Count(*) | ts | uid
> -------: | -: | --:
>        1 |  0 |  10
>        1 |  9 |  10
>        1 | 10 |  20
>        1 | 15 |  30
>        1 | 25 |  10
>        1 | 26 |  10
>        1 | 27 |  10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e76e2926ed3389fff568780017882df)*

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am sorry for providing a misleading example data where last three orders had exactly same timestamps. Real orders come paid at random timestamps, somewhere during previously paid period. 

I updated the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b0d54/1) and example data in the question - last three orders paid at 25, 26, 27 — they overlap, but that shifts the paid_till further and still results in `paid_till = 55`.

Comment: I changed my answer. check it and if you encounter another problem add data to teh example

Comment: I understand the idea!   Thank You very much for the insight!

Comment: Appears that `ORDER BY` in a sub-query is [possibly ignored](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/) or gives unexpected results. 

On the real database thus the solution gives wrong results. I.e. for a specific uid the oldest order moves to the last row in the sub-query, shifting resulting paid_till 1 extra period further.

Comment: adding a `LIMIT` clause with a large number to the sub-query seems to have fixed the issue and made the engine respect the `ORDER BY` instruction.
However this approach seems unerliable and engine-specific.

Comment: MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) advices against defining and using the same variable in a single statement:
>  The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1` evaluates `@a` first and then performs the assignment.

Comment: The statement i wrote works fine, it uses the sorted Base select, else such querys wouldn't work. Try to build an example in sqlfiddle or dbfiddle to see it shows te same behaviour.Your fiddle link uses Maysql 5.6 and there this works and even 5.7. So if you are using another version, you have to post it. If you don't like the solution, use php, Dot net js or what ever and solve the problem there. In Mysql 8 you have window function that solve this also, but you gave no indication that you are using another Verwsion than 5.6

Comment: SQL-fiddle only offers MySQL 5.6, while my prod is on **MariaDB 10.1.43** (maps to MySQL 5.7 afaik. No `WINDOW` function yet)  I failed to reproduce the `ORDER-BY` ignored behavior on SQL-fiddle and on DB-fiddle – even with the exact copy of data from my prod. So I rest my case.